# VHDL - Why does my register output change when there is neither a clock edge nor a reset?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, vivado, register-transfer-level

I have implemented a register in VHDL using the following code:

```
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

    entity reg is

      generic (
        width : integer := 8
      );

      port (
        reset, clk, en : in  std_logic;
        d : in  std_logic_vector(width - 1 downto 0);
        q : out std_logic_vector(width - 1 downto 0)
      );

    end reg;

    architecture Behavioral of reg is

    begin

      regProc : process (clk, reset, en, d)
      begin

        if reset = '1' then

          q <= (others => '0');

        elsif rising_edge(clk) and en = '1' then

          q <= d;

        end if;

      end process;

    end Behavioral;
```

I have noticed when simulating it that it is sometimes changing its output when there is neither a rising clock edge nor a reset. I have included the waveforms from the Vivado simulation below, where the event of interest occurs at the yellow marker. Can anyone explain this behavior to me please? Thanks.

[image: Register simulation]

Comment: That looks like a tool error, [another VHDL simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty8mI.png) won't do the same thing. Provide stimuli (a testbench) just to be sure. Consider removing en and d from the regProc process sensitivity list, they aren't needed and it may 'hide' a tool problem. Which Vivado revision?

Comment: show your test bench please

Comment: What xSim version are you using?

Comment: I have solved the problem. There was a issue with the surrounding logic which drove the register's reset pin. This resulted in a short spike in the reset at the point of the yellow marker, but this cannot be seen in the Vivado simulator (even when the yellow marker is moved!). I cannot seem to find the xSim version number, but it is whichever comes with Vivado Simulator 2017.1. Apologies for wasting your time, I am only just learning VHDL / Vivado and it is quite a steep learning curve!